Increasing the size limit for HTTP/2 headers in Quarkus/Vert.x
There are four configuration parameter for http/2 in quarkus:

quarkus.http.limits.header-table-size
quarkus.http.limits.max-concurrent-streams
quarkus.http.limits.max-frame-size
quarkus.http.limits.max-header-list-size

https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config
First up, trying to increase quarkus.http.limits.max-header-list-size parameter, but it wasn't enough.
Current configuration parameters measure in octets. Quarkus using Vert.x server (https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/4.5.7/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/http/Http2Settings.java).
How to increase the size of the headers using HTTP/2 protocol?
How do they affect one another?
How do I convert our byte values to current configuration parameters?

quarkus.http.limits.max-header-list-size is configuring the whole header part: the list of all the header names + values + 32 * 8 bytes per field.
To convert your byte value, just divide it by 8.
